# Best way to share an image on Facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I have a application which builds an image pretty much and I want to allow the user to share this custom image on his/her timeline (just like a normal share dialog post). I can't seem to figure out what is the best way to do this.

I'm not sure if I need to use open graph or can I just share the image somehow or what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One good way is to create a dynamic page for that image (picture.php?id=xxx), the page shows the picture and includes the necessary metatags: http://ogp.me/

`og:image` is the most important one, use the suggested size of 1200 x 630 pixels or at least 600 x 315 pixels: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/howtos/maximizing-distribution-media-content#images

Another way is to actually upload the picture, but that would include User Authorization with a Facebook App with `publish_actions` permission and you would need to go through a review process with that one too...